# awk search fields from one file within other from inside a Perl script

Tags: perl

I'm comparing below two files for duplicates

#### file1

```
ac-list hostname permit tcp host 110.185.35.111 host 10.185.38.220 eq 1222
```

#### file2

```
ac-list hostname permit tcp host 10.185.35.111 host 10.185.38.220 eq 1222
```

My script is as below

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

open( SOURCE,      "</home/amp/surevy01/file1" );
open( DESTINATION, "</home/amp/surevy01/file2" );

while ( my $line = <SOURCE> ) {

    while ( my $line1 = <DESTINATION> ) {

        chomp( $line );
        chomp( $line1 );

        my @columns = split( ' ', $line );
        my @gitcols = split( ' ', $line1 );

        my $fld1    = $columns[4];
        my $fld2    = $columns[5];
        my $fld3    = $columns[6];
        my $fld4    = $columns[7];
        my $fld5    = $columns[9];

        my $gitfld1 = $gitcols[4];
        my $gitfld2 = $gitcols[5];
        my $gitfld3 = $gitcols[6];
        my $gitfld4 = $gitcols[7];
        my $gitfld5 = $gitcols[9];

        if ( $line == $line1
            || awk '/$fld1/ && /host/ && /$fld2/ && /$fld3/ && /$fld4/ && /$fld5/' $line1 ) {

            print "\n All duplicate";
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting the below error:

> String found where operator expected at ./perltest line 25, near "awk '/$fld1/ && /host/ && /$fld2/ && /$fld3/ && /$fld4/ && /$fld5/'" (Do you need to predeclare awk?)
>   Scalar found where operator expected at ./perltest line 25, near "'/$fld1/ && /host/ && /$fld2/ && /$fld3/ && /$fld4/ && /$fld5/' $line1" (Missing operator before $line1?)
>   syntax error at ./perltest line 25, near "awk '/$fld1/ && /host/ && /$fld2/ && /$fld3/ && /$fld4/ && /$fld5/'"
>   syntax error at ./perltest line 30, near "}"
>   Execution of ./perltest aborted due to compilation errors.

However without using the `awk` command my script is working perfectly fine.

Comment: There is no "awk command" in Perl. Where did you get that from?

Comment: By `awk '/$fld1/ && /host/ && /$fld2/ && /$fld3/ && /$fld4/ && /$fld5/' $line1`, you presumably mean `grep { /$fld1/ && /host/ && /$fld2/ && /$fld3/ && /$fld4/ && /$fld5/ } ( $line1 )` (Perl has no `awk` command, but [it has a `grep` command](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I am not sure why this "comparison" is useful to you, the following code does what your code seems to be attempting to do:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $file1 = shift || '/home/amp/surevy01/file1';
my $file2 = shift || '/home/amp/surevy01/file2';

my @cols = (4, 5, 6, 7, 9);

open(my $fh1, "<$file1") or die "Cannot open source: $file1\n";
open(my $fh2, "<$file1") or die "Cannot open destination: $file2\n";

while( my $line1 = <$fh1> ) {
  chomp $line1;
  my @cols1 = split ' ', $line1;

  while( my $line2 = <$fh2> ) {
    chomp $line2;
    my @cols2 = split ' ', $line2;

    my $count = 0;
    foreach my $i ( @cols ) {
      if( $cols1[$i] eq $cols2[$i] ) {
        $count++;
      }
    }
    if( $count == scalar @cols ) {
      print "All duplicate\n";
    }
  }
  seek $fh2, 0, 0;
}
```

Regarding your code, please note:

1. As stated in comments to your question, `awk` is not a Perl command. It is a different programming language. That explains the first error you get.
2. The *string* comparison in Perl is `eq`; `==` is used to compare numbers. So you should use `$line eq $line1`.
3. You might use `awk` within a Perl script by using `system` and then get the return status using `$?`, but that would be terribly inefficient.

Also please note that the code as it stands will compare each line of the first file with all lines of the second file, giving no context to know when the `All duplicate` string is printed. Maybe you mean to compare both files side by side. For that you may want to check `diff` which combined with something that would choose the right columns like `cut`, `awk` or even `perl` would make a side by side comparison relatively easy.

If you need something else done you may want to edit your question and state what exactly you are trying to achieve and give longer input files to illustrate along with an expected output.

Comment: `split /\s+/` is almost never what you want. `split ' '` is what you should use if you want to turn a string into a list of whitespace-separated words.

Comment: @melpomene, I leave the `split` as you say. It is true that the input may contain *empty* columns and those will not be treated right with `split /\s+/`. For that `split /\s/` maybe better. But it is hard to say if we don't know the input file format.

Comment: @JavierElices `perldoc -f split`: _As another special case, split emulates the default behavior of the command line tool awk when the PATTERN is either omitted or a string composed of a single space character (such as ' ' or "\x20" , but not e.g. / / ). In this case, any leading whitespace in EXPR is removed before splitting occurs, and the PATTERN is instead treated as if it were /\s+/ ;_

Comment: @melpomene, I did not have that one in mind but you are right. Perl is full of tricks... :-) Thank you for reminding me (and others that may read this).

Comment: you have to reset the file iteration on `$fh2` with `seek $fh2,0,0`otherwise it will only iterate once.